# split String - get a section of String from the middle of a String

Tags: java, string, split

I want to get a number from a String -

```
if (list.get(k).contains("Total Weight: "))
{
    //get the number between "Total Weight: " and "tonnes" and make it a float
}
```

The String looks like this

```
Carriage ID Number: 1
Carriage type: Passenger Carriage
Tare Weight: 5.0
Total Weight: 9.725 tonnes
Number of passengers: 45
```

or

```
Carriage ID Number: 2
Carriage type: Goods Carriage
Tare Weight: 3.0
Total Weight: 8.0 tonnes
Goods Weight: 5.0 tonnes
Goods Description: Lego
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to convert String to float, I'm asking how to split the String "Total Weight: 8.0 tonnes" to create a new String "8.0" which I will then convert to float.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string using the space character, the convert the 3rd string into a float:

```
String s = "Total Weight: 9.725 tonnes";
float tonnes = Float.parseFloat(s.split(" ")[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: 
`import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    String test = (Total Weight\:)\s*([0-9]*[\.]*[0-9]*)\s*(tonnes);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile (test);
    Matcher result = pattern.matcher (yourInput);
    If result.find () yourAnswer = result.group (2);`